# Translate string within array with __ in CakePHP

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp, translation

I have an array of different priorities in my controller:
`var $priorities = array(3 => 'Low', 2 => 'Medium', 1 => 'High');`

How do I now manage to translate these values with the __-Function? I get an array that PHP expects a closing ')' bracket. This is the code I tried to use:
`var $priorities = array(3 => __('Low'), 2 => __('Medium'), 1 => __('High'));`

I use this variable to set it in my add and edit-action. These are options in a select-input and if theres a change, I don't want to fiddle around in the views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging by the `var` keyword I suspect you're trying to declare a class property here. This doesn't work, you can only declare properties using static values, i.e. you can't call any functions at this point or do any operations.

You'll need to translate the values at some later point, or assign them to `$this->priorities` later on. The `__construct` method would be a good place, if it's a controller `beforeFilter` is good too.

You'll also need to call the `__` function with `true` as the second parameter:

```
$this->priorities = array(3 => __('Low', true), 2 => __('Medium', true), 1 => __('High', true));
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not try `array_map` ?

```
var $priorities = array(3 => 'Low', 2 => 'Medium', 1 => 'High');

$priorities = array_map("__", $priorities, true);
```

Make sure to put translations in proper places. more information [here about Internationalization & Localization](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1228/Internationalization-Localization)